# Add images to a message input textview like in iPhone messages

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image, messenger

I'm making an app with messenger and want user to add images first to inputTextView, than delete image from there if they want, and then send them as a message. It's the same as in regular iPhone messenger.

I've spent few days trying to figure it, but without any success.

Does anyone have any ideas or tips how to do that?

I've attached screenshot below.

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKvrZ.png)

Comment: Show the code you have attempted so that we can see where the issue might be.  Other wise it just a guessing game.

Comment: MwcsMac, I don't have any code for that. I have code how to send text messages, but, I guess, it's necessary in this case.